# testing for NaN values: df[df['col1'] == np.nan] does NOT equal np.isnan(df['col1'])

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I am testing for `np.nan` values in a column of a pandas dataframe.

When I do: `df[df['col1'] == np.nan]` I get all `False` values even in rows where there is a `NaN`.

However, `np.isnan(df['col1'])` works as expected.

So why the discrepancy and why does the former not work.

Comment: Nothing is equal to `NaN`, not even `NaN`. That's why there's `isnan()`.

Comment: As a side note: `pd.isnull` is more robust than `np.isnan` when working with DataFrames. You should probably choose `pd.isnull` (or just `df['col1'].isnull()`) over `np.isnan`.

Comment: np.isnan does not work for string values. You right right pd.isnull is best for DataFrames and the different dtypes